# Typeset a Unix Command Inline

Tags: unix

Is there a standard and aesthetically pleasing way to typeset a unix command *inline*. For example, I may want to refer to 'ls' as I do in this sentence.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried `\verb|ls|`?

Comment: The packages mentioned in the proposed duplicate (`listings` and `minted`) both have `bash` highlighting available if needed.

Comment: @Mico Nope and that answers my questions, thanks!